# Dynamic Height for UICollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

[image]
This is my first attempt at creating a collectionView programmatically. I used a couple tutorials to get where I am now which is a Facebook/LinkedIn-esque layout with a textView and imageView. They look great when there is an image but I have no idea how to make the cell dynamically smaller in height when there is no image. I know that I currently have a fixed height of 500 but it being my first attempt, I am not sure how to set it to dynamically adjust.

I've seen a lot of Obj-C examples but nothing (that I can understand) for Swift that I know how to implement.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if let textContent = dataSource.posts[indexPath.item].textContent {
            let rect = NSString(string: textContent).boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, 1000), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin), attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)], context: nil)

            return CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, rect.height + 370)
        }

        return CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, 500)
    }
}
```

My vertical visual layout constraints (created with an extension):

```
 addContstraintsWithFormat("V:|-8-[v0(44)]-4-[v1]-4-[v2][v3(44)][v4(1)][v5(44)]|", views: profileImg, postTextView, postImageView, likesCommentsLabel, dividerLineView, likeButton)
```

Comment: I have create the same module, if you create two different types of XIB, one is include image and another XIB are only text Label, hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

**sizeForItemAtIndexPath** is one of the collection view delegate function in which you can set the height of each cell. In this delegate just add a condition.. where you can check if the cell has an image or not and based on that set the height using **CGSizeMake**

Comment: I tried this to the best of my ability but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: -(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    if(image exists in cell){
        
        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width - 10, 210);
        
    }else{
        
        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width - 10, 150);
        
    }
}